# Fractional Derivative and Laplace Transform

Tags: derivatives, definition, laplace-transform, fractional-calculus

I've learned a lot with this lecture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2FZlz4-pf-M.

I have a doubt at 14:17. Why did the professor putted the minus sign?

I also would like to know if the derivative that uses the Laplace transform is the Riemann-Liouville derivative. I think no, because if yes we could take a closed form to derivative...

So, if no in fact, has this kind of derivative some name?

Thank you so much if you could answer. Best regards.

Comment: General rule: $\frac{\partial ^nf(x)}{\partial x^n}=\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[s^n \left(\mathcal{L}_x[f(x)](s)\right)\right](x)$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk, is it general for all fractional derivative? Many thanks.

Comment: It's  Riemann-Liouville derivative:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus#Laplace_transform

Comment: Many thanks, @MariuszIwaniuk!